# how can I find which window is open child or Parent to prevent copying of URL and using it in a different page of the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an application in which I preventing copy paste of URL from Child Window to parent window
I want to know at the time of load which window is open.
I want to know which window is Used wheather it is Browser window or browser child window

How can I do that

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function Load() {
                var i = 0;
                if (typeof window.opener != "undefined") {
                    alert("I was opened from within " + window.opener.location.href);
                    window.opener =null;
                }
                else if (i == 0)
                { window.location.href = 'Index.htm'; }
                else
                {alert(i);}
            }
        </script>
```

Friends I m using this javascript to handle this Please Tell me what is wrong with this script 
Else condition is nt working for either case

Comment: Just wondering why you're not just disabling the address bar instead of going through all of this... seems like an easier way of preventing the user from changing the URL.

Comment: Even If I try to Disable address bar the Url can be copied and one can paste in main browser that is why I m doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this answer
I m sure this will help u

```
  string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Index.htm");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there two way:

1. If you open window via 'window.open' you assign some name and you can check this param of     'window' object. - `console.log(window.name)`;
2. second if you open via 'window.open' you have object 'opener'  in global object 'window' of the child window- `console.log(window.opener)`;

Comment: friend i want to prevent user to copy the url from child window and paste it in browser main window
if the code detect it is a browser window not the child window i want to redirect him to a predefined page
i hope you got what i meant

Comment: just type in console "typeof window.opener" and you will see - even if this is simple window 'typeof window.opener' will return "object", that's why you else condition don't work.I tried in Chrome.

Comment: What should I use can I use only window.opener for comparision